# Alternative to hyperlinks with JqueryUI Mobile ListView

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a page using JqueryUI Mobile. More specifically it uses JqueryMobile Lists

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-ul.html

I love the look, feel, and usage of the listview, but I have come into a problem.

The users need to be able to click the link quickly, which is difficult with how I do it now. The link performs a PHP function, then redirects back to page they was on and the cycle restarts. Now that I am getting more familiar with AJAX, I would like to be able to have them click the link, it updates the database, then calls my AJAX script to update the data without the refreshing the page.

This would enable the users to be much much quicker with the tasks as most of the down time they have currently is the few seconds it takes to refresh (or more accurately be redirected back to) the page. When if its possible they would like to be able to click a link every second or even more if they are able to.

**My question is: How can perform a database update based on dynamically generated links from a MySQLi database without requiring the user to refresh? I** believe once I have that, I could also use Ajax to update the list every quarter second or so. I've considered using buttons, but I'm not sure how that would tie into listview, since listview seems to be only based on  links.

On a side note - are their standard practices with often Ajax should update? Is there any guidelines I should follow?

Here is a sample of my current code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{

}
else
{
$_SESSION['error']="You are logged in.";
header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<style>

.split-custom-wrapper {
    /* position wrapper on the right of the listitem */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.split-custom-button {
    position: relative;
    float: right;   /* allow multiple links stacked on the right */
    height: 80%;
    margin:10px;
    min-width:3em;
    /* remove boxshadow and border */
    border:none;
    moz-border-radius: 0;
    webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    moz-box-shadow: none;
    webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.split-custom-button span.ui-btn-inner {
    /* position icons in center of listitem*/
    position: relative;
    margin-top:50%;
    margin-left:50%;
    /* compensation for icon dimensions */
    top:11px; 
    left:-12px;
    height:40%; /* stay within boundaries of list item */
}

.ui-icon-delete:after{
    background-color: #B22222 !important;

background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20fill%3D%22%23FFF%22%20points%3D%2214%2C3%2011%2C0%207%2C4%203%2C0%200%2C3%204%2C7%200%2C11%203%2C14%207%2C10%2011%2C14%2014%2C11%2010%2C7%20%22%2F%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

.ui-icon-home:after{
    background-color: #A2CD5A !important;

}
.ui-icon-arrow-u-r:after{
    background-color: #3D59AB !important;

}
</style>
</header>


  </head><center>  <h2 style="">Empty For now<br><br>
    </h2></center>
<a href="home.php" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left" data-ajax='false'>HOME</a>
<a href="ViewOrderMobile.php" class="ui-btn ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-left" data-ajax='false'>VIEW / EDIT CURRENT LINE</a>
<br><br><br><br>
<center><center>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content"style="margin-top:-75px;">

    <h2 style=""></h2>
    <ul data-role="listview">
  <?php 
include "../../includes/databaseconnections/demo/database_connection.php";
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
else{}
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (ID) WHERE Table1.feild1 = '0' ORDER BY dateSelected ASC LIMIT 25";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['photoLink'] == NULL)
        {
            $row['photoLink'] = "endofgroup";
            $row['lastName'] = "End Of Group " ;
            $ID = "&ID=".$row['ID'];
        }
        if ($row[leftGym] == "1") { $flash = "style='color:#B22222;font-size:140%'";} else {$flash ="";}
            echo "<li><a href='button1.php?sid=${row['ID']}' $flash  style='font-size:140%;' width='25px' data-ajax='false'>&nbsp;  &nbsp;  {$row["lastName"]}, {$row["firstName"]} ({$row["pmBusNumber"]})</a><div class='split-custom-wrapper'>

            <a href='button2.php?sID={$row['ID']}&lane=1{$ID}'  data-role='button' class='split-custom-button' data-icon='delete' data-rel='dialog' data-theme='c'  data-ajax='false' data-iconpos='notext'></a>           
        </div></li>";
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
 mysqli_close($link);

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
    </ul><br>

</div> 
 </div>

 </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you update here ? I can see that you have a link `button1?... ` which looks like it's getting something. What about the update ?

Comment: The button1.php and button2.php are just placeholder names for other PHP files. once click the buttons goto that page, and then are redirected back to this page.

Comment: You want to perform an ajax update without page refresh, which is possible. But what should update when i click ? I don't see any data passed to update.

Comment: @Searching Right now all that is passed is a get statement to that page sending the ID that is generated from the MySQL Transaction. All I would really like to do is send that ID to the page, and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added comments to the code snippet. Please let us know if you require further info.
Based on jquery [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) v3.1.1

html: update the `a` element in the list with `class=myCustomClass`

```
<a href='button1.php?sid=${row['ID']}' $flash  style='font-size:140%;' width='25px' data-ajax='false' class='myCustomClass'>&nbsp;  &nbsp;  {$row["lastName"]}, {$row["firstName"]} ({$row["pmBusNumber"]})</a>
<div class='split-custom-wrapper'>
<a href='button2.php?sID={$row['ID']}&lane=1{$ID}'  data-role='button' class='myCustomClass split-custom-button' data-icon='delete' data-rel='dialog' data-theme='c'  data-ajax='false' data-iconpos='notext'>
</a>           
</div>
<span id="status"></span>
```

script :

```
$(function () {

    //Attach the click event to Links only with class=myCustomClass and perform this function
     $("a[class=myCustomClass]").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //preven the page from navigating, the default behaviour for a link
        $.ajax({
            url : this.href, //perform a ajax request with the link, GET in this case
            /* type: POST, */
            beforeSend : function () {
                $("#status").text('Working..')
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data); //do something with the data if any
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("ERROR"); //report in console for errors
            console.info(jqXHR);
            console.info(textStatus);
            console.info(errorThrown);
        }).always(function () {
            //do this step every time 
            $("#status").text('completed..')
            console.info("completed"); irrespective of result
        });
    })
```

Comment: testing now. Thank you.

Comment: It looks as if its still wanting to go to the next page - Is the prevent default() what is supposed to be stopping the redirect? I also tested changing the data-ajax to true with same result.

Comment: you are correct that's the one to prevent it.Do you see any errors in the console log. the code is against  jquery 3.1.1. did you add the class to the link ?

Comment: @RobertDickey hang on a sec i'll modify that to support jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1 with jquery Mobile Version 1.4.5

Comment: I was about to say - when I put in 3.1.1 it seems to have disabled the listview layout of the jquery mobile.

Comment: @RobertDickey which version of jquery Mobile do you prefer to use ?

Comment: I currently use <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Comment: the code still is same. mobile 1.4.5 with jquery 2.1 looks good. https://jsfiddle.net/30933y9e/1/

Comment: for jquery 1.11.3 use `$("a.myCustomClass")` instead of `$("a[class=myCustomClass]")`

Comment: testing with your version 1.4.5

Comment: It seems to be causing my other Ahrefs on the page to no longer redirect, not just the ones where I set the class. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: It should only do it for links with `class=myCustomClass` rest should have the original behavior

Comment: I figured out how to resolve that - the only issue i have left is that for some reason jquerymobile isn't loading with the Ajax. it works, but doesn't use the look of jquerymobile. im researching it now